# String replacement in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection that has a number of documents where the `title` contains encoded `&` characters (`&amp;`) and I would like to convert these back.

I'm wondering if it is possible to do a string replacement on a value based on it's original value.

For example with the document below:

```
{
   title: "this &amp; that"
}
```

Is it possible to replace the `&amp;` with a normal update statement?  I tried something like this:

```
db.questions.update({title: /&amp;/}, {title: title.replace(/&amp;/g, "&")});
```

But it threw the following error: `ReferenceError: title is not defined`

Can it be done using an update statment?  If not, is the best way just to do a find/foreach/update on each document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I'm wondering if it is possible to do a string replacement on a value based on it's original value....Can it be done using an update
>   statment?*

Currently, it is **not** possible to update a field's value in mongodb by **accessing**,**modifying** its original value in a single update statement.

> *But it threw the following error: ReferenceError: title is not defined*

This error occurs, because Mongodb does not see the `title` field of the document that is getting updated in its scope.

> *If not, is the best way just to do a find/foreach/update on each document?*

Yes. You need to do it that way.

```
db.collection.find({"title":/&amp/}).forEach(function(doc){
db.collection.update({"_id":doc._id},
                     {$set:{"title": doc.title.replace(/&amp;/g, "&")}})
})
```